# PDO não retorna count

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Preciso armazenar a contagem de resultados, mas aparentemente com o PDO não consigo armazenar o valor. Já rodei o `select` por fora e vem o resultado, porque não consigo armazenar na variável `$flag` o resultado?

```html
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as flag FROM RESERVAS
              WHERE DATA_RETORNO_REAL = '0000-00-00' AND
                    COD_VEICULO = :veiculo and
                    DATE_FORMAT(DATA_SAIDA, \'%d-%m-%Y\') = :data_reserva
                    ";
    $data = $conexao->prepare($query);    // Prepare query for execution
    $data->execute(array(
    ':veiculo' => $veiculo,
    ':data_reserva' => $data_reserva
    ));
    $saidas = $data->fetch();

    $flag = $saidas['flag'];
```

Por fora:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Faça isto - `var_dump($saidas);` - e coloca o retorno aqui.

Comment: resolvi tirando o DATE_FORMAT(DATA_SAIDA, \'%d-%m-%Y\') = :data_reserva e substitui por data_saida = curdate(). Não sei pq aqui as \ não funcionam....

Comment: Agora que o dizes, com o `\'` estavas a escapar as aspas (`'`), por esa razão não funcionavam, experimenta colocando `DATE_FORMAT(DATA_SAIDA, '%d-%m-%Y')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remova as barras de `DATE_FORMAT(DATA_SAIDA, \'%d-%m-%Y\')`, barras seguidas de aspas(simples ou duplas) escapam elas ou seja a aspas estava sendo interpretada como parte da string e não como o delimitador.